# CNN for Brain Tumour Detection using 3D MRI images

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, conv-neural-network, mri

I am looking to implement a CNN to detect Alzheimer disease using 3D MRI dataset containing healthy and diseased samples. I am getting a very low efficiency using LeNet and VGG16. My models aren't learning and I have around 300 images total. I am trying 3D as well as 2D convolution.

The main problem is handling the 3D images. Please do help

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It might help if you posted some code so we can better assist you.  [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [some advice](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from [SO's king](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), Jon Skeet

Comment: For starters, what do you mean by "low efficiency" ?  Training time, or accuracy with your models?  What kind of GPU do you have, if any?  You will probably need to vectorize your code.  cs231n is a great course on this that I've taken, and [this assignment](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2019/assignment1/) teaches you to vectorize your code in numpy.  There are [many solutions sets](https://github.com/Arnav0400/CS231n-2019) to these problems online, if you ever get stuck, but please attempt them on your own first.  Or you could hire someone reputable to do this for you.  Best of luck!

Comment: I am getting 50% validation accuracy after training for 50 epochs on the LeNet architecture. I am using Google Colab to train the model. But the problem is the val_acc just remains the same after each epoch that means the model is not learning. I couldn't find any other way .

Comment: What time frame do you have?  If you need it soon, I don't really have good advice.  If you have some time, I would recommend the course.  Also, please post some intermediate steps in the question so someone can help you

Comment: Hope this helps.  Sorry I don't have time to debug your work right now.  Please add further comments if you have questions